# equivalent of some JS codes in python

Tags: python

So I'm new to Django and I have a few questions, what's the equivalent of this JS code into python?

```
function multiply(a, b, cb){
 cb(a*b);
}

multiply(5, 6, (res) => {
 console.log(res)
})
```

also, I searched online but couldn't find a clear answer, do python have the same `async` function as JS with `await`?

Do python have `promise` functions just like JS with res and rej?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting a few things mixed up. But here is your code answer first:

```
def multiply(a, b, cb):
    cb(a * b)

multiply(2, 4, print)
```

The callback is supposed to be a function. So in this case, `print` is the function.

Where you might be a little confused:

- python is not async OOB like JS
- python does have async and await, but not like JS
- the above is really your equivalent of `promises` from JS.
- If you really want to use fat arrow functions like in JS, python equivalent is lambda functions.

Dont get the languages confused.